# React cannot set state of react Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a function to send an email. But state is not updating for setLoading,setLoading1. Initailly both loading is set as false. The console *console.log("no",loading,loading1);* returns *no false false* and console *console.log("load",loadingState)* *returns load false*.
All other functionality works correctly.

```
async function submitEmail(pr) {
  let complete = await errorMessageHandler();
  if (complete == "") {
    if (pr == "No") {
      let loadingState = loading;
      console.log("load", loadingState)
      await setLoading(!loadingState);
    } else {
      await setLoading1(true)
    }
    console.log("no", loading, loading1);
    RNSmtpMailer.sendMail({
        mailhost: "mail.oscon.net",
        port: "465",
        ssl: true,
        username: "**********",
        password: "********",
        from: "**********",
        recipients: "************",
        subject: "New Registration From Mobile app",
        htmlBody: emailContent(pr),
        attachmentPaths: [],
        attachmentNames: [],
      })
      .then(success => {
        setLoading(false);
        setLoading1(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setLoading(false);
        setLoading1(false);
      });
  }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). *(Since this is a question about React state, the fact you're using React Native doesn't have to prevent you creating a MRE using React.)*

Comment: Assuming `setLoading` and `setLoading1` are state setters (e.g., from `useState`), they don't return promises and `await`ing them is pointless. Other than, that the above doesn't provide enough context for us to really be able to help.

Comment: showing the way you implemented your hooks may help us to figure out the problem, before that can you try to move  console.log("no",loading,loading1); inside .then() to make sure it's not executed before the setState, which is waiting for resolve and console.log is not.

Comment: const[loading,setLoading]=useState(false);
    const [loading1,setLoading1]=useState(false);  this is How define my state. No use of putting console in .then() statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is a kind of async operation but it does not return Promise so awaiting them is pointless and the code like this:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false)
setMyState(true)
console.log(myState)
```

just send your wish to change the state to React, but does not actually change it, no matter if you use async-await here or not. And the console log shows you the initial value because it is a part of main call stack, not an async operation.

If you want to catch the moment when your state is changed use ComponentDidUpdate for class based components or useEffect hook for functional components.

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false)
...
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(myState) // show when myState is changed
}, [myState])
```

Comment: thanks. Your content helped me to solve the problem.